# How to query for entities with no matching siblings, with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I've got the two following entities ...

```
class Citation
{
  public int CitationId { get; set; }
  public string Identifier { get; set; }
}

class CitationIdentifier
{
  public int CitationIdentifierId { get; set; }
  public string Identifier { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to query for all `Citation` records where the `Identifier` property does not match any of the `CitationIdentifier.Identifier` property. So, if I have a `Citation` with an `Identifier` property containing "foo", but there are no `CitationIdentifier` records with an `Identifier` property containing "foo", then I'd like to retrieve that `Citation`.

I'm working with an `IDbSet<Citation>`.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What queries have you tried so far, and in what way have they failed to solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe an except clause? Select all of them except the ones that share an identifier:

```
(from citation in Citation select citation)
.Except(
from c in Citation
join ci in CitationIdentifier on c.Identifier equals ci.Identifier
select c);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this one:

```
var result = citations.Where(x=>!citationIdentifiers.Any(y=>y.Identifier==x.Identifier));
```

where I suppose that `citations` and `citationIdentifiers` are collections that contain all the citations and citation identifiers respectively you have.

Using the `Any` extension method, you are trying to check if there is any citation identifier with the value of identifier equal to the identifier value of the current citation record. If so, then this citation will not be inluded int the result, since we take the negation, of

```
citationIdentifiers.Any(y=>y.Identifier==x.Identifier)
```

inside in our `Where` extension method.

Comment: At first I was chagrinned at being beaten to the answer, but today I learned to use `!collection.Any(predicate)` instead of `collection.Where(predicate).Count == 0`